# How is the Nuaulu palm leaf carrying pot made?

Tags: survival

In a Ray Mears BBC Demo, [The Importance of the Sago Tree](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ps7626gqL48), he travels to Seram in Indonesia and witnesses the natives using Sago leaves to create this really cool pot at `2:40`:

[image]

The [Nuaulu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuaulu) tribesman twists the leaves together, somehow causing them to lock into place:

[image: Twisting the leaves]
[image: Leaves lock into place]

Unfortunately, Ray "didn't even attempt it". However, perhaps there is someone here who has and would be generous enough to teach us the technique?

Answer (score 4):

I would say to look up basic basket/container weaving techniques. The First picture obviously shows some form of stitching around the middle of the container, as well as when they are packing the Sago into the leaf container for transportation home. The basic mechanics for weaving can be applied to just about anything that is flexible and retains its shape once formed.

Comment: Geistvon - Have a look at the video: there is a very clever technique used to interlock all the leaves. It appears to be closer to origami than basket weaving

Comment: I have. I can't figure it out and I can't seem to find anything about how to fold them, and this is after (literally) searching for 3 hours. Closest I found was this Vase http://www.origami-instructions.com/easy-origami-vase.html